# Экспорт текста с Javascript

Tags: javascript, export

Как можно экспортировать выделений текст в файл?

Answer (score 1):

берете текст , переводите в json выделаете что вам надо и распоряжаетесь по назначению...
это если получить текст с файла , чтобы экспортировать то выберете файл делаете json добавляете текст в json и создаете новую копию файла...
 [Export a Json object to a text File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33780271/export-a-json-object-to-a-text-file)

```
  var txtFile = "/tmp/test.txt";
   var file = new File(txtFile,"write");
   var str = JSON.stringify(JsonExport);

   log("opening file...");
   file.open(); 
   log("writing file..");
   file.writeline(str);
   file.close();
```